# Accessing Google Analytics Saved Reports with the Python API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I know that custom reports are not possible to access using python API. Is there any way, to access the saved reports.
Instead, I want to know if it's possible to just download the CSV from a python script, with a precise date.

So I will just have to run the script with a precise date to get my saved report, then I will run another script on the Excel/CSV file.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the Google analytics api to request the same data in your reports, there is no api that will let you find out what custom reports a users has created though.

Comment: @DalmTo Can I access saved reports?

Comment: There is **no** api to access any of the reports custom, saved,  standard or user created.  With the single exception of [unsampled reports](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports)  There is no API to access any of the formatting in the Google Analytics web application.   The only thing you can access is the data.